# format magento collection query?

Tags: mysql, magento

I am loading a magento collection, and echoing it's select query trough getSelect() method.
However, it returns me a huge not formated query (all in one line)...it is very hard to debug it this way...

Does anyone know a way to somehow simply format sql queries?

I know that in phpmyadmin, if you make a select and run it, somehow it formats it very nicely, but for this query it doesn't happen.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, found the answer after googling a little:

http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

This link takes you to a website, were you are required to enter your sql query in a text box, select the language (mssql, mysql..etc) and simply by clicking Format Sql, it renders you a formated version of the sql you just entered

very usefull site :)